# How to add a grid view under Master-Detail detail page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a grid view at the bottom of the screen containing 'Current Playing' information about a media being played in a media player. The problem is that I want this view to be there no matter what is the page visible.

The main layout is a Master-Detail page for the navigation menu panel, where  the detail page should contain everything.

The detail page can be a content page, a navigation page (mostly) or a modal content page. However, if I might only choose one, I would choose it to be a navigation page.

So, simply I want to do something **like** this:

```xml
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Page x:Name="viewPort" Grid.Row="0">
                    <!--This page source is dynamically set from the code behind...-->
                </Page>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <!--Here should be the rest of my grid structure...-->
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

But wrapping a page inside another view/page is not possible, I tried also modifying the Master-Detail page control template to add that grid at the bottom of the detail page and display whatever page above it, but no luck in finding the original template or even setting a template for Master-Detail layout...

I'm new to Xamarin but somewhat experienced with c# and xaml, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ContentPresenter` with control template.

Create a control template in App.xaml> Application.Resources> ResourceDictionary.

```
  <!--  Grid Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    BackgroundColor="Accent"
                    Text="Grid Template" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

And then use it in detail page.

```
ControlTemplate="{StaticResource GridTemplate}"
```

[image]

I have uploaded the project on GitHub for your reference. 
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/ControlTemplate_ContentPresenter/MasterDetailPageDemo

**Updated:**

For data binding of control template, you could use `TemplateBinding`.

Create a AppViewModel:

```
 public class AppViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Name_A";

    public AppViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

App.xml:

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"  />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Accent" Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Name}" />

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Set the binding in each page which use the control template.

```
  this.BindingContext = new AppViewModel();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, that is what I'm trying not to do, as now the grid is indeed visible in the two pages and I can use the same principle for the item pages as well, but the problem is that each time a page changes, the whole grid is recreated, and now I'm no longer having a static grid feeling and it just flickers meaning it reloads. Moreover, I'm no longer having the same controls, meaning that I'll have to deal with unknown number of reloads and eventually I'll end up creating global variables to set... Or maybe a databinding... But again, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have updated my reply with how to use binding of control template. You could take for reference.